# Can't execute /msg resend command in Nickserv

Tags: irc

Never received confirmation email form Nickserv IRC registration - can't execute the

> /msg resend

command in Nickserv to resend the conf. Any ideas? Haven't used IRC in years. I get "invalid command". Using Adium for OS X.

Answer (score 1):

Restart your client.
It helped me - maybe they changed some things that only take effect if you close and reopen the connection.

Answer (score 0):

This will be dependant upon the server you're using, but generally something like

```
/msg nickserv resend
```

or

```
/nickserv resend
```

will work. Do keep in mind that this is very network specific.

Comment: No go, still getting:      "(notice) Invalid command. Use /msg NickServ help for a command listing."

Comment: Did you register the account >24h ago? If so the account will be dropped and you have to re-register. From [link](http://freenode.net/faq.shtml)

Comment: Registered 14 hours ago - that doesn't help me here - but I guess I'll just wait to re-register